# Convert LPTSTR to System::String^ for view

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, type-conversion, lptstr

I need to convert LPTSTR to String^ for be able to view it via MessageBox;

```
LPTSTR szResult;
DWORD language = GetPrivateProfileString(L"LANGUAGE", L"LANGUAGE", L"", szResult, 255, L"\\file.ini");
System::String^ str_buffed = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(szResult);
MessageBox::Show("CLR MessageBox", str_buffed, MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Exclamation);
```

Am I doing it in good way? Because I got en exception: System.AccessViolationException - Attempting to read the protected memory

How can I read in other way ini file and convert it (returns) to String^ ?

Comment: szResult should be defined as something like TCHAR szResult[501]; Access violation occurs because for an outbound parameter you are passing a pointer to an un-allocated memory location.

Comment: An AVE is *never* the "good way".  The obvious bug is your szResult declaration, it needs to be a TCHAR[] and cannot be a LPTSTR.  Lying with 255 should have made you uncomfortable *before* making this mistake.

Comment: As for the explanation: LPTSTR is a pointer type (the "P" in the name). It doesn't allocate buffer memory. It isn't initialized, so it can point anywhere, most likely to nullptr. Chances are less than one in a million that your app said it is using the address in `szResult`. And if it did, you want something else at that memory location than what `GetPrivateProfileString` puts there (and good luck finding that bug).